# How do I copy data from REST API endpoint into Azure DB using Data Factory v2?

Tags: rest, api, azure-data-factory

I want to do a one time pull of everything in Wisconsin from this Web API Endpoint. https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives/representativeInfoByDivision

Then I want to load the data into an Azure DB that I created.

I've reviewed several articles and videos and I haven't made much progress. I currently have the following; an Azure subscription, a storage account, an Azure SQL Server and DB.  I've tried using the Copy Data activity in my Data Factory. For the source Base URL I'm using https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives. The "Test Connection" is successful.  For the next screen "Data Set" for the entry "Relative URL" I'm using the same thing and it's giving the following error. "Relative Url Fail to read from REST resource"

I expect to be able to map the data from the Google API to columns in tables that I create in my Azure DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/ as base URL and representatives as relative URL.

And the end, relative URL will be concat with base URL. And  try rest connector of ADF. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest